# Excel VBA Code for TextBox data to a selected Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have data inside my Textbox and I want to have the same data to show in My Selected Cell "F3". If I change the data/text in my TextBox the information will show in my selected Cell as well. Is that possible?

Comment: Is that possible? Yes. I think you mean to ask: How can this be done? In which case, you're also on the wrong site. There are many tutorial and learning sites, Stack Overflow is here to solve specific problems, not provide introductory tutorials of programming. Try researching it on your own first and come back when you run into specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private sub Textbox1_TextChanged
       Range("F3").Value = TextBox1.Text
end sub
```